# Simple GET Request in .NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make a GET request to my server to fetch Messages giving 2 parameter. I send this GET request:

```
http://localhost:62020/api/Chat/GetRecentMessages?RoomId=1&LastMsgId=0
```

And my controller should handle it:

```
[HttpGet]
        private List<ChatMessage> GetRecentMessages(int RoomId, int LastMsgId)
        {


            int count = 0;
            int timeout = 30;
            int timeoutCount = 0;
            List<ChatMessage> messages = new List<ChatMessage>();

            //go until we get a result or we time out
            while (count == 0 && timeout >= timeoutCount)
            {
                var result = Db.ChatMessages.Where(r => r.RoomId == vm.RoomId).Where(r => r.Id > vm.LastMsgId); // Get all messages from Room that are more recent than last message
               count = result.Count();

                if (count == 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    timeoutCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                   messages = result.ToList();
                }
            }

            return messages;
        }
```

But I keep getting a 404 errors saying that it could not find this route. What do I need to do on my controller side in order to get these 2 values?

Comment: How are your routes defined?  Is this an API controller or a vanilla MVC controller?

Comment: it is an API controller

Answer (score 5):

How about making the action public? You cannot directly call a private action.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even realize that was private. Thanks, I will try it out now